# How to set text font & size through html in a lable

Tags: html, ios

I am facing a problem to set text alignment in center through HTML. Below is my code

```
NSString *welcomeStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div font face='Helvetica Neue' size='5' color = 'black' align=\"center\" ><b>Hello Worlds</b></font> </div> <div font face='Arial' size = '4' color = 'black' align=\"center\">Hi! welcome to my app. I think you all are fine. Thanks for visit our site </font> </div>"];

NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[welcomeStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

mylable.attributedText = attrStr;
```

My output is :

[image]

But my problem is i am not getting proper text size what i gave and font name also. By default its coming like image. My font name is *Helvetica Neue* but its coming different font.

Please anybody help me.

Comment: That's incorrect HTML.

Answer (score 2):

i got my answer. My answer is:

```
NSString *welcomeStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div font face='Helvetica Neue' size='5' color = 'black'> <center><b>Hello Worlds</b></center></font> </div> <font face='Arial' size = '4' color = 'black'><center>Hi! welcome to my app. I think you all are fine. Thanks for visit our site</center>"];

NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[welcomeStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

mylable.attributedText = attrStr;
```

Instead of **align=\"center\"** i add

```
<center>mytext</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you get mixed up with @font-face (css).

You must declare in your div something like

```
<div style="font-family:'Helvetica Neue'; font-size:'16px';"></div>
```

Be aware that you must import your font if it's not a common font.

Answer (score 0):

Helvetica Neue is not a web-safe font; i.e. not everyone has it on their computer. You need to use a web safe font or import a font for to web. Google provides a library of free fonts for use on the web: https://www.google.com/fonts

You will need to import the font and then assign it to the div. This will best be done as a stylesheet, not as an inline style. Google provides simple instructions and code snippets on how to use their fonts properly.